# Importing web data

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, data-import

I trying to import web data to excel using vba with below code but it seems like not working.Hopefully someone can help to fix this issue, thank you very much!

```
Sub ExchangeRate()
Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
ieObj.Visible = True
ieObj.navigate "https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/ert/GUI/Pages/Report.aspx?CU=%27SGD%27&EX=REP&P=OneWeek&CF=Compressed&CUF=Period&DS=Ascending&DT=Blank"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("default").Item(2).getElementsByClassName("row1").Item(4)
    With ActiveSheet
      .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
      .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
      .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
      .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
    End With

    i = i + 1

Next htmlEle

End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't specify the fields you wish to grab from that webpage.

Comment: "not working" is not a very useful description of the specific problem you're having when you run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is the line where your selecting the elements you want to read data from.

```
Sub ExchangeRate()
Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
Dim htmlEleCollection As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
ieObj.Visible = True
ieObj.navigate "https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/ert/GUI/Pages/Report.aspx?CU=%27SGD%27&EX=REP&P=OneWeek&CF=Compressed&CUF=Period&DS=Ascending&DT=Blank"

' Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
While ieObj.readyState <> 4 Or ieObj.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
' using application.wait may work, but if it takes more than 5s for the page to load your code may fail.
' waiting for the browser to be ready is better.


Set htmlEleCollection = ieObj.Document.getElementsByClassName("default").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("row1")
' i dont think you are selecting the right object with your code, i think this is what you were aiming for?

For Each htmlEle In htmlEleCollection
    If htmlEle.Children.Length > 1 Then
' the table header has one child, the data rows have more
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
'            .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
'            .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
' children 3 and 4 do not exist when i view the page so your code will fail with them in.
        End With
    End If

    i = i + 1

Next htmlEle
ieObj.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for your kind support! it is extremely helpful to me as a newbie in VBA